# How to fetch products with aMember API

Tags: php, api, amember

I am using http://www.amember.com/docs/REST

Products Endpoint - 
http://example.com/amember/api/products?_key=APIKEY

The thing is its works to check access they show subscriptions of valid products but when I go to fetch products I end up having -

```
{ "ok":false,
 "error":true,
 "message":"API Error 10003 - no permissions for products-index API call" }
```

Can anyone please help on how to integrate it
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

from amember admin section go to "Remote Api Section",click on edit button for which you have used key in api url.

select following checkboxes of Permission section :
    1.products - Products
    2.billing-plans - Product Billing Plans

after saving details check your response by :
    http://example.com/amember/api/products?_key=APIKEY